# Getting RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED error when trying to write a 2MB object in Momento Serverless Cache

Tags: caching, serverless, momento-cache

Currently getting the `RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED` error back when trying to write an object to my cache. Is there any way to increase this limit to support bigger objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but you need to contact Momento support (support@momentohq.com) to get this soft limit increased.

For more information on limits, [check their documentation](https://docs.momentohq.com/manage/limits).